# UiAutomator exited unexpectedly with code 4294967295, signal null

Tags: appium-desktop

It was working fine few minute before. Now i am getting following error in Appium Desktop app while trying to launch the app from appium Desktop.

Appium Desktop : version 1.10.0

> [UiAutomator] Starting UiAutomator [UiAutomator] Moving to state
>   'starting' [UiAutomator] Parsing uiautomator jar [UiAutomator] Found
>   jar name: 'AppiumBootstrap.jar' [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\Infotmt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s 4200856de42a655b push 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-android-driver\bootstrap\bin\AppiumBootstrap.jar'
>   /data/local/tmp/' [ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
>   [ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\Infotmt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s 4200856de42a655b shell ps' [ADB] Attempting to kill process
>   15133 [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\Infotmt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s 4200856de42a655b shell kill -0 15133' [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\Infotmt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s 4200856de42a655b shell kill -0 15133' [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\Infotmt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s 4200856de42a655b shell whoami' [ADB] Cannot kill PID 15133 due
>   to insufficient permissions. Retrying as root [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\Infotmt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s 4200856de42a655b shell kill -0 15133' [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\Infotmt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s 4200856de42a655b shell kill -0 15133' [UiAutomator] Error
>   while killing uiAutomator: Error: Unable to kill uiautomator
>   processes. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error:
>   'Command
>   'C:\Users\Infotmt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   -P 5037 -s 4200856de42a655b shell kill -0 15133' exited with code 1'; Stderr: '/system/bin/sh: kill: 15133: Operation not permitted'; Code:
>   '1' [UiAutomator] Starting UIAutomator [ADB] Creating ADB subprocess
>   with args:
>   ["-P",5037,"-s","4200856de42a655b","shell","uiautomator","runtest","AppiumBootstrap.jar","-c","io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap","-e","pkg","eu.niko.smart.naswi.personalization","-e","disableAndroidWatchers",false,"-e","acceptSslCerts",false]
>   [UiAutomator] UiAutomator exited unexpectedly with code 4294967295,
>   signal null [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'

Answer (score 1):

Running a cold reboot on the emulated device resolved the above issue for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know it's not the best answer but when that happened to myself I deleted my VirtualDevice and create a new one then started working again...Sorry but I didn't know how this happens

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but if I setup a sort of 'keep-alive' by calling 'adb devices' every n second, such error was gone.
I'm using Win10 powershell, like this:

```powershell
do { D:\Users\jjunior\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices; sleep 5; } while($true)
```

HTH

**UPDATE: nevermind, in my case was a cable issue; replaced it by a new one and all it's working as expected.**